# What am I doing wrong with this do loop?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I'm trying to write a do loop that will continue to ask for a person’s name until the name "Bob" is entered.  If the name is not Bob, the response should be “You’re not Bob”.  If the name is Bob, the response should be “Hi Bob” (then the loop ends).

```
public class loopExtra3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        name=Bob;

        do {
            System.out.println ("What is your name?");

            if (name.equals("Bob") == false) {
                System.out.println("You're not Bob");
            }
            if (name.equals("Bob") == true) {
                System.out.println("Hi Bob");
            }
        } while (name.equals("Bob") == false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the second if to an else statement.

Comment: We don't normally write `==true` - it's redundant - and `==false` can be simply converted to the `!` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't even compiling, since it has to be `name="Bob";` - if you fix this, your code works like a charme. But the main problem is that you aren't even asking for a input, so the code will run endlessly with a name which is not Bob.

With reading the input, everything works:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    do {
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        if (!name.equals("Bob")) {
        System.out.println("You're not Bob");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("Hi Bob");
        }
    } while (!name.equals("Bob"));
    }
}
```